# How would this be deobfuscated [conditional statement with bitwise exclusive or]

Tags: java, bitwise-operators, deobfuscation

Whats the equivalent of this without ixor `~`

```
if(~(i3 + -1) < -1) { ... }
```

.

would it be this?

```
if((i3 + 1) > 0)  { ... }
```

or (doubt this?)

```
if((i3 + 0) > 0)  { ... }
```

or (doubt this?)

```
if(i3 < -1)  { ... }
```

Thanks I cannot really test it out myself well I can.. but I'm writing a deobfuscator and I want to be 100% sure.

Comment: Note that `~` is not XOR, it's a unary operator which performs a bitwise complement.

Comment: `~` is OPCODE `IXOR` in java which i'm deobfuscating, but yeah i understand it is used in bitwise operations

Comment: @SSpoke: evidently IXOR is not the same thing as XOR, or perhaps it's an immediate XOR with -1, which is the same thing as a bitwise complement ? BTW, please try to tag more appropriately in future - there was no clue that this was in any way a Java-related question - I've fixed it now.

Comment: Yeah here is the description. `IXOR` - Pops two integers off the operand stack. Computes the bitwise exclusive or of value1 and value2. The integer result replaces value1 and value2 on the stack. Sorry

Comment: so XOR is the exclusive OR what is IXOR? called opcode is called - 
integer bitwise exclusive or

Comment: IXOR is Inclusive-OR which is OR

Comment: thanks for the knowledge mate.. Guess some sites are unreliable.. http://www.daimi.au.dk/dOvs/jvmspec/ref-_ixor.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`~x` is the *bitwise* (not logical) inversion of `x`.  In two's complement, it is equal to `-1 - x`.  Try it.

```
~0  = -1 -  0 = -1
~-1 = -1 - -1 = 0
~1  = -1 -  1 = -2
```

Now, to apply this to your condition:

```
-1 - (i3 - 1) < -1
-1 - i3 + 1   < -1   # commutative property of multiplication
   - i3       < -1   # 1 + -1 == 0
     i3       >  1   # * -1 inverts everything, including the inequality
```

Note, this only applies if the numbers are two's complement -- but almost all CPUs (and most programming languages) behave that way these days.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm assuming this is Java and that `i3` is an `int` (would work the same with `byte`, `short`, or `long`).

`i3 + -1` is `i3-1` which is just going to be some integer.
`~` is bitwise not. So we've subtracted one and negated all the bits. This is the exact opposite of negating a [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) number. (Negating a two's complement is usually done by adding 1 then complementing). Fortunately this operation is its own inverse, so doing the opposite is also a way to negate a 2's complement of a number. So we've ended up with just `-i3`.

You're left with `-i3 < -1` which is the same as `i3 > 1` which is as unobfuscated as it can get.

Answer (score 0):

`~x` is actually `-x - 1`
Hence, `-(i3 - 1)` is equivalent to `-(i3 - 1) - 1` whcih is equal to `-i3`
So,

```
if(~(i3 + -1) < -1) { ... }
```

is equivalent to:

```
if(-i3 < -1) { ... } // or simply if(i3 > 1) { ... }
```